# searching an element in jTable java

Tags: jtable, rowfilter

so here is example how one dude did it

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class TestTableSortFilter extends JPanel {

private String[] columnNames
        = {"Country", "Capital", "Population in Millions", "Democracy"};

private Object[][] data = {
    {"USA", "Washington DC", 280, true},
    {"Canada", "Ottawa", 32, true},
    {"United Kingdom", "London", 60, true},
    {"Germany", "Berlin", 83, true},
    {"France", "Paris", 60, true},
    {"Norway", "Oslo", 4.5, true},
    {"India", "New Delhi", 1046, true}
};

private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
private JTable jTable = new JTable(model);

private TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter
        = new TableRowSorter<>(jTable.getModel());

private JTextField jtfFilter = new JTextField();
private JButton jbtFilter = new JButton("Filter");

public TestTableSortFilter() {
    jTable.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(new JLabel("Specify a word to match:"),
            BorderLayout.WEST);
    panel.add(jtfFilter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(new JScrollPane(jTable), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    jtfFilter.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            String text = jtfFilter.getText();

            if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
            } else {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            String text = jtfFilter.getText();

            if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
            } else {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
           JFrame frame = new JFrame("Row Filter");
           frame.add(new TestTableSortFilter());
           frame.pack();
           frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
           frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    });
}
}
```

and its working fine but problem is when i try to get value from click with this line

```
((DefaultTableModel) jTableZ.getjTable1().getModel()).getValueAt(row, 36))
```

It doesn't return the row this program searched, instead I get returned row thats was placed in the jTable in the first place, without the search.Let my try to explain:
When I have multiple rows in my jTable and the search narrows it into 1 row I will get in return the first row in my old jTable,not the row program searched it. How to resolve this?

I forgot to write that my data is not as here but like

```
private Vector<Vector<String>> data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it instead getSelectedRow i had to conver it into rowIndexModel to get the selected row

```
private int row = jTable1().getSelectedRow();
private int rowModel=jTable1().convertRowIndexToModel(row);
```

and it worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

To search through a JTable try something like this:

```
For(int row=0;row<C.ROWS; row++){
   For(int col=0;col<C.COLS; col++){
     if(table.getValueAt(row, col) == (Object) O){
         System.out.print(Hello); 
      }
   }
}
```

Depending on wether or not you set what the value can be in each cell on the JTable I used object for this occasion.

Comment: my program crashes when i try somting like this